# Upload file Laravel 5 registration

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I am trying to use the built in registration of Laravel 5 to upload a photo for each user.

I have made the changes that i needed in:

- views/auth/register.blade.php
- app/User.php
- app/services/Registrar.php

And registration works fine.

But when I try to add the file upload logic, my problem is in Registrar.php.

I have added:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

but in the **create method** using:

```
Request::hasFile()
```

returns an error of can't use as static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dependancy injection.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FooController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        dd($this->request->hasFile('key'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. is it some where in the Docs? that i can use request->hasFile('key') insted of Request::hasFile('key')

Comment: actually, since it was complaining about being _can't use as static_, so i used dependancy injection. good thing about laravel is, you can accompolish the same in different way. i rarely use facades though. dependancy injection is more convenient as you have seen above.

Answer (score -1):

With laravel 5.*
please comment the first line and use the second line.

line 1 :
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;

line 2 :
use Request;

Comment: Not answering the question